# What would be Regular Expressions (Regex) to check string for start with $ and does not end with special character

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

In my string, I only allow the following 5 special characters @_.-$

```
RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@$_.\\-]+$/
```

How do I check if a string is starting with character $
also, another looking for RegExp for a string to not end with a special character

Comment: I hope that's not JavaScript.

Comment: @MikeM .ts file. 
Declaring validators for the input field.

Comment: @mkirr His point is that `RegExp` is the name of a built-in class in JS, you shouldn't redefine it.

Comment: If this is JS, why do you have the `qregularexpression` tag? That's a class used in the Qt library, not JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_regexp = /^\$[a-zA-Z0-9@$_.\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

This omits the special characters from the character set of the last character.

Comment: In that case, any suggestions on how can I resolve it?

Comment: What do you need to resolve?